# Override rails update_all method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to override the rails (active record) `update_all` method so that it always updates the `updated_at` field as well. How should I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the following code in a file `/config/initializers/update_all_with_touch.rb`

```
class ActiveRecord::Relation

  def update_all_with_touch(updates, conditions = nil, options = {})

    now = Time.now

    # Inject the 'updated_at' column into the updates
    case updates
      when Hash;   updates.merge!(updated_at: now)
      when String; updates += ", updated_at = '#{now.to_s(:db)}'"
      when Array;  updates[0] += ', updated_at = ?'; updates << now
    end

    update_all_without_touch(updates, conditions, options)
  end
  alias_method_chain :update_all, :touch

end
```

It automatically adds the parameter `:updated_at => Time.now` whenever you use `update_all`.

**Explanation:**

This snippet use [`alias_method_chain`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/alias_method_chain) to override the default of `update_all`:

```
alias_method_chain :update_all, :touch
```

The method `update_all` is replaced by the method `update_all_with_touch` I've defined, and the original `update_all` is renamed `update_all_without_touch`. The new method modifies the `upgrades` object to inject the update of `updated_at`, and next call the original `update_all`.

Comment: This solution works, however I'm not clear on how exactly this is working. What are the methods update_all_without_updated_at, or update_all_with_updated_at? Also, different formats of update_all have been used in the code, and as such updates can be a hash, or an array or a string. I can check the type and merge the updated_at parameter for a hash, and that is working, but what about when its an array or a string?

Comment: @user523146 I've modified the snippet  to handle String and Arrays, and added some explanation. Update the file and restart your server to see the changes.

Comment: I've replaced `with_updated_at` by `with_touch` for clarification.

Comment: Does over riding this method globally will help while expecting the same changes for rails console? @Baldrick

Answer (score 2):

You can override the update_all method in your model:

```
 def self.update_all(attr_hash) # override method
    attr_hash[:updated_at] = Time.now.utc
    super( attr_hash )
 end
```

Comment: I need this behaviour in more than one model, and hence I was looking for a method which would work across models.

Comment: So Add an ActiveRecord superclass and add the function into there. It would then be available for all your models