# How to override update_all for model & relations for specific models only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to produce a module that protects against errant use of `update_all`, and other callback ignoring methods.

I have a module:

```
module UpdateProtection
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods  
  end 

  module ClassMethods
    def update_all(updates)
      if updates.is_a? Hash
        updates.merge!(updated_at: Time.now)
      elsif updates.is_a? String
        updates = "updated_at = '#{Time.now.utc.strftime('%F %T')}'," + updates
      elsif updates.is_a? Array
        updates[0] = "updated_at = '#{Time.now.utc.strftime('%F %T')}'," + updates[0]
      end 
    end
  end
end
```

that I am including in the models that I want to have this protection. I have a model with a default scope. If I call:

`MyModel.update_all(name: 'foo')`

I get the expected result:

```
SQL (4.1ms)  UPDATE `my_models` SET `my_models`.`name` = 'foo', `my_models`.`updated_at` = '2016-09-26 14:46:02' WHERE (my_models.scope_condition is not null)
```

However, if I call:

`MyModel.unscoped.update_all(name: 'foo')`

I get:

```
SQL (4.6ms)  UPDATE `my_models` SET `my_models`.`name` = 'foo'
```

and my module's implementation of `update_all` is not used.

If I call:

`MyModel.method(:update_all).source_location`

it returns the path of my module, whilst if I call:

`MyModel.unscoped.method(:update_all).source_location`

it returns:

`/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.4/lib/active_record/deprecated_finders/relation.rb`

[update]

When calling `update_all` on `MyModel.unscoped`, it's actually being called on the relation object returned by that class method.

I've spotted this solution, which would sort of work:

[Override rails update_all method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076886/override-rails-update-all-method)

but this would override update_all for every model in the application, whereas I would like to do so only for specific models.

Rails/AR version is 4.0.12

Comment: I would argue that you shouldn't change the behavior of Rails core methods. If you need some protection just override your method like this: `def update_all(_); raise "Do not use \`update_all\`, because reasons..."; end`

Comment: I also recommend against this core behaviour override... But at a guess, this is probably something to do with class hierarchy; you could try using `prepend` (and `self.prepended`) instead of `include`?

Comment: Whilst I would tend to agree, in this case I am fine with it. Your version still modifies the core method, after all, just in a less useful more potential-for-breaking-things way. Pragmatically I think I'd sooner take on the potential headaches of overriding the method than allow future developers to break functionality depending on an accurate `updated_at` value.

Comment: The breaking behavior of my example should blow up in the tests. That allows the developer to fix it by using the `correct` method instead of using the *incorrect* version and wondering about the strange behavior...

Comment: Which is fine unless some third party code depends upon being able to call `update_all`, in which case it feels like having a bump to the timestamp is far less likely to cause problems, right?

Comment: I would argue that a third party developer probably used `update_all` instead `update` by purpose. I for example use the methods that do not update the timestamp, when I change records for statistical or caching reasons, whereas the timestamp IMO should show the date when the user or its action triggered the update.

Comment: Sure, but in either case if third party code calls your version of `update_all`, it will raise the error and fail. I understand the trade off I'm making with this design isn't ideal, I just feel it's preferable to the one you propose. For my use case it will always be better to have perhaps overzealous updates to the timestamp than to prevent calling update_all entirely